# Question - Calculating Coefficients for 2nd Order Transient Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

I am struggling with calculating the coefficients for second order transient analysis.

For example, when analyzing a underdamped circuit, we know that the equation for voltage or current is
\$x_{t}=e^{-αt}(K_{1}\cos(\sqrt{ω^{2}-α^{2}}\:t )+K_{2}\sin(\sqrt{ω^{2}-α^{2}} \:t))\$

Then in order to determine for example \$v_{(t)}\$, I would first determine what \$v_{(0)}\$ is, and plugging in 0 for all values of t in the above equation, I would get the result \$v_{(0)}=K_{1}\$.

Then the next step in calculating \$K_{2}\$, I need to take the derivative of \$v_{(0)}\$ in order to determine the coefficient.

However, when following these steps, my solution isn't always correct when comparing it to the book solutions. Sometimes they utilize \$v_{(0)}\$ and \$v'_{(0)}\$, and other times they use \$v_{(0)}\$ and \$i_{(0)}\$ to determine these coefficients.

Some examples: https://ibb.co/233Zd0q <---- In this they use \$i_{(0)}\$ and \$i'_{(0)}\$, which makes sense because you’re using current and its derivative.

https://ibb.co/DMyDfM4 <---- In this, they use \$v_{(0)}\$ and \$i_{(0)}\$, but I don’t understand why they use both current and voltage. Since we’re solving for current, I would assume you have to use current and it’s derivative.

I would greatly appreciate help with this, thank you in advance.

Edit: I have added my work for the second problem, in which I attempt to get \$K_{1}\$ and \$K_{2}\$ using \$v_{0}\$ and \$i_{0}\$, as well as \$i_{0}\$ and \$i'_{0}\$.

When doing it the first method, I get \$K_{1}=-4\$ and \$K_{2}=22\$, while the second method I get \$K_{1}=4\$ and \$K_{2}=-2\$.

Method 1: https://ibb.co/d59W0yk
Method 2: https://ibb.co/fSP9sFX

Not only are my K values different, my final current in both cases is also different, as can be seen at the bottom of each image.

Edit 2: Thank you to user215805 for pointing out my mistake. I kept plugging in my K values into \$i'_{(0)}\$ rather than \$i_{(0)}\$.

Comment: Arbitrary constants can be found from initial conditions using various ways to avoid longer calculations (unless "various ways" Are mathematically reasonable) but  you can use your approach to find K1 and K2 in question 2 from I(0) and dI/dt(0) {as you mentioned} and you'll  get the same value of K1 and K2

Comment: When using i(0) and v(0), I get K1=-4 and K2=22; however, when I use i(0) and di(0)/dt, I get K1=4 and K2=7.

Comment: My work for i(0) and v(0): ibb.co/XL4CY11 and my work for i(0) and di(0)/dt: https://ibb.co/FxnYxPk

Comment: 1.why you have taken L=1/2?  2.and be careful k1 k2 used in voltage function is different from K1, K2 used in current function (that you have assumed) , so if you're comparing the value of K1 and K2 of current function then you have to compare with

Comment: K1= . 48+ . 16k2 and K2=.64-.12k2(where k1, k2 are constant of voltage function)

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally used L=0.5 H in the circuit instead of 1 H. I am correcting it right now. I will update my answer accordingly, along with the final answer of i(t) for both methods.

Comment: Complete work for method 1: https://ibb.co/d59W0yk                                                                Complete work for method 2: https://ibb.co/fSP9sFX

Comment: Again you make a mistake in third last row of 2nd fig., you have to put values of k1, k2 in I(t) not in di/dt for expression if I(t)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I kept plugging it in to the wrong equation by mistake. I don't even know why I was plugging it in there. I guess I need todo a better job at double-checking my work. Thank you for the help!